# Create constraints in rails migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, apartment-gem

I have a migration that create a named constraint

```
execute(%Q{
  ALTER TABLE dreamflore_clients
    ADD CONSTRAINT unique_clients UNIQUE( client, no_adresse );
})
```

But in `schema.rb`, rails turn this part into an index

```
add_index "dreamflore_clients", ["client", "no_adresse"], name: "unique_clients", unique: true, using: :btree
```

The problem is we are using `Apartment` and newly created tenants have an index instead of the constraint and we are using the postgreSQL feature `ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT`

For now the solution is to rollback some migrations and migrate again, but this is a really dirty hack

How to stop rails creating this index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using structure.sql instead of schema.rb by running `rake db:structure:dump`?

schema.rb has some limitations regarding syntax and switching to structure.sql ought to solve this issue.

You can make the switch to structure.sql permanent by adding `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql` to environment.rb.